# Hello, when I run rosdep update, i get 'timed out'

Tags: rosdep, rosdep-install, update, github, rosdistro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

after running 'rosdep update', it shows:

```
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit http://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml

ERROR: unable to process source [http://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml]:
    
<urlopen error _ssl.c:489: The handshake operation timed out> (http://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml)

ERROR: error loading sources list:
    The read operation timed out
```

this is my first time to install ROS, and I don't know how to deal with this error..  What I have to do now?  Thank you!

Hello demmeln~

after I run  `python -c 'from urllib2 import urlopen; print(urlopen("http://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml", timeout=5).info());'`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 625, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 625, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1215, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)

urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
```

now after running rosdep update...:

```
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d

ERROR: unable to process source [https://github.com/NikolausDemmel/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml]:
    <urlopen error _ssl.c:489: The handshake operation timed out> (https://github.com/NikolausDemmel/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml)

Hit https://github.com/NikolausDemmel/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml

ERROR: unable to process source [https://github.com/NikolausDemmel/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml]:
    <urlopen error _ssl.c:489: The handshake operation timed out> (https://github.com/NikolausDemmel/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml)

ERROR: error loading sources list:
    The read operation timed out
```

really thank you demmeln~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146731/hello,-when-i-run-rosdep-update,-i-get-%27timed-out%27../) by [liuhyuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/14146/liuhyuu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-03-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liuhyuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/14146/liuhyuu/) on 2014-04-02**:
if you have the same problem .maybe you can try to repeat the command 'rosdep update'.. I don't know what happened but sometimes it really works ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you please edit your answert to print the output of excuting in your terminal:

```
cat /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
```

From the error message it seems like there is a missing second slash after `http:/`, but that might just be formatting.

Are you able to view `http://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml` in your browser and download it in the terminal with `wget http://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml`?

Also, are you using ubuntu? Which version? How have you installed rosdep (apt or pip?) and is your installation up to date?

**Edit:**

Have you executed the `rosdep update` command repeatedly? Does it always fail the same way?

What does `rosdep --version` output?

**Edit2:**

You can directly check the following, if it is a problem that is not really related to rosdep, but rather either github, your local setup or python:

```
python -c 'from urllib2 import urlopen; print(urlopen("http://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml", timeout=5).info());'
```

**Edit3:**

So this really comes down to your machine / your python urllib2 not timeing out on that address, which seems not to be a problem with rosdep as such. <s>You could try one thing, and replace the contents of file `/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list` with and see if that makes a difference for the `rosdep update` call.</s> **Update:** Don't do that, it doesn't seem help and if you forget to undo it, you are left with stale sources.

```
# os-specific listings first
yaml https://github.com/NikolausDemmel/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml osx
yaml https://github.com/NikolausDemmel/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml gentoo

# generic
yaml https://github.com/NikolausDemmel/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml
yaml https://github.com/NikolausDemmel/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/python.yaml
yaml https://github.com/NikolausDemmel/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
gbpdistro https://github.com/NikolausDemmel/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml fuerte
gbpdistro https://github.com/NikolausDemmel/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/groovy.yaml groovy
gbpdistro https://github.com/NikolausDemmel/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/hydro.yaml hydro
```

**Edit 4**:

Ok, I'm out of ideas, it seems to be that some urls you can access, and some URLs you can't. Maybe it is a github problem, maybe it is a problem of your computer. You could try with a different machine or a virtual machine from the same network to narrow it down further. Or try with your machine from a different network. It's probably best to remove the file you just changed `/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list` and call `sudo rosdep init` again.

**Edit 5**:

The problem seems to persist for multiple people and changing URLs. Some people report success after trying multiple times and/or across multiple days.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liuhyuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/14146/liuhyuu/) on 2014-04-01**:
yes， I tried a lot of times... but it always fail.
rosdep --version: 0.10.25

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-01**:
I'm not sure what is going on. It is strange that you are able to access the file with wget but not rosdep...

**Comment by [liuhyuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/14146/liuhyuu/) on 2014-04-01**:
this problem really makes me crazy..

could you please executed the rosdep update command and post the result？ thank you a lot!

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-01**:
You can always continue the installation without rosdep, for example by editing the file `/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list` to comment out any files you can access at the moment. After that, the update should complete. You have to be aware that rosdep will not be fully functional, but

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-01**:
it should be possible to get started with ROS even without rosdep. If you install the packages from apt, you don't need rosdep anyway. You only need it if you build additional packages from source, end even then, there  are ways to work around it.

**Comment by [liuhyuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/14146/liuhyuu/) on 2014-04-01**:
thankyou a lot! but when I exacuted rospack depends1 xx ,it shows:

[rospack] Error: the rosdep view is empty: call 'sudo rosdep init' and 'rosdep update'

**Comment by [liuhyuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/14146/liuhyuu/) on 2014-04-01**:
Thank you ～ thankyou a lot~

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-01**:
is it working now?

**Comment by [Xure](https://answers.ros.org/users/14191/xure/) on 2014-04-01**:
I've met the same problem, I'm going to be crazy...

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-02**:
@william any idea what's going on with github connectivity with urlopen for some people on some addresses?

**Comment by [liuhyuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/14146/liuhyuu/) on 2014-04-02**:
@Xure   oh，try to repeat rosdep update...  I exacuted this command times and times and finally it works...

**Comment by [liuhyuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/14146/liuhyuu/) on 2014-04-02**:
@demmeln  I update success after 2-day's time repeating exacuted 'rosdep update'..    and finally i don't even know why it suddenly works..  anyway，thank you a lot～

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-02**:
@liuhyuu: good to know, thanks. You could my answer as accepted, if you want. ;-)

**Comment by [liuhyuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/14146/liuhyuu/) on 2014-04-02**:
@demmeln of course ～ thank you very much ～

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-04-02**:
I'm not sure, but I am confident that it is related to the roll out of their CDN.